# How to deploy SCSS file to dist in angular 6?

Tags: sass, angular6

We have a need to deploy scss files to dist directory when angular is building. I am fully aware that only css should be deployed after the build however we have custom need to read the scss file on run time and perform certain action.

I tried adding below line (last line under scripts:) in angular.json file but that did not help. I cant find any file deploying during debug.

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/scss/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "src/scss/_custom-variables.scss"
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/scss/_custom.scss"
        ],
```

Adding this under assets in angular.json file works for me. I was looking under wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Out of the box;** angular 6 does not provide a way to do this natively. However; you can achieve what you are describing by using [custom webpack configuration](https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01) that utilizes Angular 6 builders.

For example, you can use [Custom Webpack Builder](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack). Due to the nature of builders,their configuration is merged with CLI own configuration, so all you need to do is to create a minimalistic configuration utilizing [Webpack Copy Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin); then use glob patterns to catch & copy all required `.scss` files to `dist/` directory.

You can try to fiddle with similar webpack configuration:

```
"use strict";

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: "src/app/**/*.scss",
          to: "dist/app/"
        }
      ]
    )
  ]
};
```

**Alternatively;** if you do not require ejected SCSS during development and only in production package, you can use simple [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) task to copy the files

```
"use strict";

let gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("copy:styles", () =>
  gulp.src(["src/app/**/*.scss"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/app/")));
```