# Including SCSS file in a library and use it in another library

Tags: angular

i have a library in angular 8 and i need include a file SCSS in the dist for used in another library, how i make this thing?

Any idea for make this?

[image: Example]

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: ok, it's a simple library and i want to export a scss file and i try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423026/how-to-include-sass-styles-in-an-angular-8-library  but not works for me and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453929/how-to-deploy-scss-file-to-dist-in-angular-6 but not works eaither.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like this:

step 1: Upload the version of angular to the 9.

step 2: Your package.json from your library must be like this,
        the key is "assets"

```
{ 
"$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",`enter code here`"dest": "../../dist/test-lib",
      "assets": ["**/yourTheme.scss"],
      "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
      }
    }
```

step 3: Type ng build in your console and verify that the dist contains your theme or your styles.scss

**NOTE**: If you need that the same but for the version 8 try the following
https://www.usefuldev.com/post/Angular:%20create%20a%20library%20that%20supports%20Angular%20Material%20theming